# Error when trying to run a 2nd query node js and sqlite3: SQLITE_RANGE: bind or column index out of range

Tags: node.js, sqlite, ejs

I am creating an web app that displays a list of names from a sqlite3 database. I am trying to generate a profile page for each name using the user id. I am getting the error 'SQLITE_RANGE: bind or column index out of range'. I have had a look at some similar questions however, I have been unable to find a solution that works.

app.js page:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const allAgents = require('./models/all-agents');
const profilePage = require('./models/profile');
const ejsLint = require('ejs-lint');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'));

let db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/agents.db');


app.get('/', function (req, res){
  allAgents.getAllNames(db, function(err, rows){
    console.log(rows);
    res.render('index', {listName: rows});

  });

});

app.get('/profile/:profileId', function (req, res){
  let profileId = req.params.profileId;
  profilePage.getProfileInfo(db, profileId, function(rows){
    res.render('profile');
    console.log(rows);
  });
});


app.listen(3000);
console.log('connected to port 3000');
```

all-agents.js: (This works fine, I am able to display the name list in ejs and have generated a link to the profile page using the user id).

```
  module.exports.getAllNames = function(db, callback){
  let sql = `SELECT agentId id, agentName name FROM agents ORDER BY name`;
  params = [];

  db.all(sql, params, function(err, rows){
    if (err) return callback(err);

    return callback(err, rows);


  });
};
```

profile.js:(The query that i want to run is commented out, I tried using the first query to make sure the sql statement wasn't wrong. For some reason this does not work either).

```
module.exports.getProfileInfo = function(db, profileId, callback){
  /*let sql = `SELECT teams.teamName Team, agents.agentName agent FROM teams INNER JOIN agents
              ON teams.teamId = agents.teamId`;*/
    let sql = `SELECT agentId id, agentName name FROM agents ORDER BY name`;
  params = [profileId];
  db.all(sql, params, function(err, rows){
    if (err) return callback(err);
    return callback(err, rows);
  });
};
```